SQLITE3 --- BASH SCRIPT ---Single quote or double quote
In a bash script using sqlite command, when to use single quote and when to use double quote.
Can somebody explain me why using double quote does not work but single quote does work :
Single quote :
    TEST_SQLITE () {

echo
echo "#
# --- 6
#"
echo
sqlite3 "$DATABASE_LOGGER" << EOF
.output "$TMP_SQLITE_DIR/temp5"
select id,SCRIPT_NAME from datalogger where SCRIPT_NAME = '$SCRIPT_NAME' ;
EOF
echo
echo "cat $TMP_SQLITE_DIR/temp5"
cat $TMP_SQLITE_DIR/temp5

}

TEST_SQLITE

Result :
1|01-script_install_master_sys_config_script.sh

Double quote :
TEST_SQLITE () {

echo
echo "#
# --- 6
#"
echo
sqlite3 "$DATABASE_LOGGER" << EOF
.output "$TMP_SQLITE_DIR/temp5"
select id,SCRIPT_NAME from datalogger where SCRIPT_NAME = "$SCRIPT_NAME" ;
EOF
echo
echo "cat $TMP_SQLITE_DIR/temp5"
cat $TMP_SQLITE_DIR/temp5

}

TEST_SQLITE

got this error :
Parse error near line 2: no such column: 01-script_install_master_sys_config_script.sh
  d,SCRIPT_NAME from datalogger where SCRIPT_NAME = "01-script_install_master_sy
                                      error here ---^

Thank you for helping.

In SQL itself (the language), double quotes are used as object delimiters, eg table names. This allows specifying names with spaces in them, eg "my table". You can't use them to specify strings. Some database products have additional custom delimiters, eg \my table`in MySQL and[my table]` in SQL Server

This has nothing to do with bash, you'd have the same problem with any other method of running the SQL query. It's just basic SQLite syntax.
